# Is it possible to change the output of CRM_Core_Error::debug($form)?

Tags: drupal, forms, debugging

Currently, when I inspect the form structure in CiviCRM using CRM_Core_Error::debug($form), the output is presented as text, which makes it difficult  to investigate.
[image]

I'd like to find a way to make the output of CRM_Core_Error::debug($form) more user-friendly and similar to Drupal's Devel module's expandable items. I tried using krumo($form), but it didn't work. Any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do similar to CRM_Core_Error::debug_var but using the html dumper:

```
$dumpForm = (new \Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\HtmlDumper('php://output'))
  ->dump((new \Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\VarCloner())->cloneVar($form));
CRM_Core_Error::debug($dumpForm);
```

and then there's little expandy triangles on the right of expandable lines:

[image]